# Scroll to element when clicking table of contents

Tags: reactjs

**In React, how can I scroll to a heading on the page, when the corresponding heading is clicked in my table of contents?**

1. I parse my markdown document to generate a TOC:

```
const toc = [
    {    id: 'lorem',    title: 'Lorem'    },
    {    id: 'ipsum',    title: 'Ipsum'    },
    {    id: 'dolor',    title: 'Dolor'    }
];
```

2. I then render this TOC in `render()`::

```
{ toc.map((entry) => {
return (
    <li key={entry.id}>
        {entry.title}
    </li>
);
})}
```

3. When I click on an entry in my TOC, I would like the page to scroll to the `h2` element with that `id`. How?

The examples I have seen all use `ref`. But I am not sure how to use `ref` in my case, where the TOC is created dynamically at runtime and hence the refs would need to be created dynamically? I cannot add them to my document's elements, since they are generated by markdown-to-jsx.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add IDs to your Markdown headers in your Markdown files and you can add IDs with this syntax:

`### Lorem {#lorem}`

Then in your React code you render the TOCs with link tag linking to header IDs:

```
{ toc.map((entry) => {
return (
    <li key={entry.id}>
        <a href={`#${entry.id}`}>{entry.title}</a>
    </li>
);
})}
```

To read more about Markdown ID syntax: https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#heading-ids

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even consider not using `ref`. This appears to do the job!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting my answer.